# ng-grid Access sorted array data

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I need to access the array of sorted data after sorting a table since the original is unchanged.

There is an `gridOptions.ngGrid.filteredData` but no `gridOptions.ngGrid.sortedData`

How can I access the sorted array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than just changing the appearance of the data in the grid, you could resort the data itself…if you use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy), you can add a function and modify the `headerCellTemplate`, as shown below.

**Modified `headerCellTemplate`:**

```
<div class="ngHeaderSortColumn {{col.headerClass}}" ng-style="{'cursor': col.cursor}" ng-class="{ 'ngSorted': !noSortVisible }">
  <div ng-click="mySort(col.displayName)" ng-class="'colt' + col.index" class="ngHeaderText">{{col.displayName}}</div>
  <div class="ngSortButtonDown" ng-show="col.showSortButtonDown()"></div>
  <div class="ngSortButtonUp" ng-show="col.showSortButtonUp()"></div>
  <div class="ngSortPriority">{{col.sortPriority}}</div>
  <div ng-class="{ ngPinnedIcon: col.pinned, ngUnPinnedIcon: !col.pinned }" ng-click="togglePin(col)" ng-show="col.pinnable"></div>
</div>
<div ng-show="col.resizable" class="ngHeaderGrip" ng-click="col.gripClick($event)" ng-mousedown="col.gripOnMouseDown($event)"></div>
```

**New function:**

```
$scope.mySort = function (field) {
  $scope.gridOptions.data = _.sortBy($scope.gridOptions.data, function (item) {return item.field});
};
```

The only change I made to the default template is on the second line where I changed the value of `ng-click` from `col.sort($event)` to `mySort(col.displayName)`

Comment: Thanks this should work but it would break multisort. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction as it caused me to discover a better way. I modified ng-grid's sortService there is a function called  `sortActual` where it copies the data into `tempData` variable like so:  `var tempData = self.data.slice(0);` By simply removing the `splice(0)` it will sort the data in place aka the original array and no further work is neccesary. Thanks !

Comment: Maybe this can be a config option https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/1056#issuecomment-37974396